# Serverless.js and Lambda@Edge: specifying origin

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-edge

I'm trying to create a CloudFront distribution (using Serverless.js) that has two origins (both S3 buckets).  There's a default origin that serves the public website, and an origin for paths starting with `/attachments`.  That second origin has a `viewer-response` Lambda@Edge function that handles some authentication.

The current implementation is deployed using some homegrown scripts and a JSON CloudFormation template, which works.  I'm trying to get rid of those idiosyncratic scripts, however, and standardize on Serverless.js (which has at least has the benefit of being a standard tool).

However, I'm having difficulty bending Serverless.js to my will here.  Here's the `resoruces` section of my `serverless.yml` file (the relevant bits, at any rate):

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    CloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          // all the usual properties...PriceClass, Enabled, etc omitted for brevity
          DefaultCacheBehavior:
            TargetOriginId: AppBucket
          Origins:
            - DomainName: foo-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com
              Id: AttachmentsBucket
            - DomainName: foo-app.s3.amazonaws.com
              Id: AppBucket
```

That part works fine, and the origins are created correctly.  Attaching the `viewer-response` function is where things start to go sideways:

```yaml
functions:
  viewerRequest:
    handler: viewerRequest.authorize
    events:
      - cloudFront:
          eventType: viewer-response
          pathPattern: '*-resources/*'
          origin: ????????
```

The [official documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudfront) seems to indicates that you specify origins with a URI, like `s3://foo-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com`.  When I try that, I get CF errors, and it's clear why.  If I look at the actual generated update template (`./serverless/foo-template-update-stack.json`), this is what I see (only the relevant bits):

```json
  "CloudFrontDistribution": {
    "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
    "Properties": {
      "Origins": [
        {
          "Id": "AttachmentsBucket",
          "DomainName": "foo-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com"
        }
      ],
      "CacheBehaviors": [
        "TargetOriginId": "s3/foo-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

Note the mangled `TargetOriginId`.  What it *should* be is `AttachmentsBucket` (at least that's what would work in the old homegrown scripts).  Note that it also mangles the URI, which is weird because that's what it seems to expect.

I've tried:

- Specifying the entire second origin in the function (got both Serverless.js and CloudFormation errors)
- Using `AttachmentsBucket`; Serverless.js complains, and what gets written into the update template is `custom/NullAttachmentsBucket` (clearly it wants a URI)
- Half a dozen other things I can't remember.

Serverless.js would make this deployment a lot more idiomatic -- and I like that it handles the fussy aspects of updating Lambda@Edge functions -- but I can't make it do what I want!

Comment: Serverless expects you to define the origins inline with your events. You shouldn't be defining them in your resources section.

Comment: Hi, @AndrewGillis!  Yes and no?  The Serverless.js documentation (which is not great) does show that, but if you dig deeper, there's additional documentation that shows you an also do it in the resource section...which you'll need to do to define multiple origins.  If you have an example of providing it in the events section that has multiple origins, I would love to see it.  At this point, I'm thinking of just moving to CDK.

Comment: @AndrewGillis, the examples towards the bottom of this page show the use of the resources section: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudfront.  Perhaps you need to provide *both*?  But I don't see an example of that, or how to link the two.

Comment: You can use the resource section for other configuration, just not origins as the framework defines them at synth-time. [This is the relevant code in serverless framework](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/e0764531efe597fba574a030b06fba1855ba61ac/lib/plugins/aws/package/compile/events/cloud-front.js#L334). I definitely recommend CDK. They have useful constructs for handling lambda@edge in particular.

Comment: Just realized why you're getting stuck. Serverless doesn't support adding an origin without any events attached. When you provide one in the resources section it overwrites the origins generated from your event definitions. Anyway, opt for CDK and use the "experimental" EdgeFunction construct. It handles the special deployment needs of edge functions nicely in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I used this serverless plugin for link a cloudfront distribution resource with a lambda function [Serverless Plugin: Support CloudFront Lambda@Edge](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge)

It worked for me

```
service: image-resizer--delivery-data-6

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  authenticateFunction:
    handler: authenticate/index.handler
    lambdaAtEdge:
        distribution: 'MyCloudFrontDistribution'
        eventType: 'origin-request'

  resizeImageFunction:
    handler: resize-image/index.handler
    lambdaAtEdge:
        distribution: 'MyCloudFrontDistribution'
        eventType: 'origin-response'
resources:
  Resources:
    ImagesS3Bucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: ${self:custom.s3Bucket}       

    MyCloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          DefaultCacheBehavior:
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: 'false'
              Cookies:
                Forward: none
            AllowedMethods:
            - HEAD
            - DELETE
            - POST
            - GET
            - OPTIONS
            - PUT
            - PATCH
            TargetOriginId: ImagesS3BucketOrigin
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
          Origins:
          - DomainName: bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
            Id: ImagesS3BucketOrigin
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity:
                Fn::Join:
                  - ''
                  -
                    - 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/'
                    - Ref: cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity                         

    BucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        Bucket: !Ref ImagesS3Bucket
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            - Sid: PublicReadGetObject
              Effect: Allow
              Principal: '*'
              Action:
                - s3:GetObject
                - s3:PutObject
              Resource: arn:aws:s3:::${self:custom.s3Bucket}/*
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  aws:SourceArn:
                    - !Join
                      - ''
                      - - 'arn:aws:cloudfront::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:distribution/'
                        - !GetAtt MyCloudFrontDistribution.Id

    cloudfrontoriginaccessidentity:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
      Properties:
        CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
          Comment: "Cloudfront dist's OAI" 

plugins:
  - '@silvermine/serverless-plugin-cloudfront-lambda-edge'

custom:
  s3Bucket: S3BUCKETNAME
```