# How do I trigger a function on a CloudFront event for a distribution that I already have defined in the resources section of my serverless.yml file?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, serverless, serverless-framework

Using the serverlesss framework, I have defined a CloudFront distribution in the resources section of my serverless.yml file.  Now, I have two functions that I would like to trigger on CloudFront events.

According to the serverless [docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudfront#cloudfront-distribution-configurations), it's ok for the distribution configurations to be set in the resources block of the serverless.yml.  However, if I do this, I'm not sure how I link this to my functions with the `origin-response` and `viewer-request` event types.

Defining the CloudFront distribution's origin under the functions (as shown in the serverless docs) is not sufficient for my use case as I need to define additional configurations like an alias for my distribution. So if I define the distribution under the resources block, how do I link my functions to it?

Comment: CDK or Terraform will be a better option for this use case.  Also something similar raise here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75342712/serverless-js-and-lambdaedge-specifying-origin

Answer (score 0):

To reference the CloudFront distribution created in the `resources` section of your `serverless.yml` file in the Lambda trigger, you can use the CloudFormation intrinsic function `Fn::ImportValue`. Here's an updated example:

```yaml
service: myService

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  myFunction:
    handler: handler.myFunction
    events:
      - cloudFront:
          eventType: viewer-request
          distributionId: ${Fn::ImportValue: MyCloudFrontDistributionId}

resources:
  Resources:
    MyCloudFrontTrigger:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity
      Properties:
        CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
          Comment: CloudFront Origin Access Identity

    MyCloudFrontDistribution:
      Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
      Properties:
        DistributionConfig:
          Origins:
            - Id: MyS3Origin
              DomainName: <your-s3-bucket-url>
              S3OriginConfig:
                OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${MyCloudFrontTrigger}"
          Enabled: true
          DefaultCacheBehavior:
            TargetOriginId: MyS3Origin
            ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - HEAD
            ForwardedValues:
              QueryString: false
              Cookies:
                Forward: none
          Comment: My CloudFront Distribution
```

In this example, the `distributionId` property of the Lambda trigger is set to `${Fn::ImportValue: MyCloudFrontDistributionId}`. You'll need to replace `<your-s3-bucket-url>` with the URL of your S3 bucket.

Before deploying this configuration, you'll need to export the CloudFront distribution ID value in your CloudFormation stack. For example:

```yaml
Outputs:
  MyCloudFrontDistributionId:
    Value:
      Ref: MyCloudFrontDistribution
    Export:
      Name: MyCloudFrontDistributionId
```

By exporting the distribution ID, you can import it in the Lambda trigger using `Fn::ImportValue`. This way, you can reference the CloudFront distribution created in the `resources` section.

Hope this helps or gives you idea on the right direction

Comment: Can you provide any links to documentation that show where the `distributionId` field is?

Comment: you're right forgot this would only be possible with the plugin https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-lambda-edge-pre-existing-cloudfront. Note did the above yaml while validating everything so might have missed some configuration from the plugin.